# Django errors submitting imagefield in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django form I'm trying to submit to my server. When the submit button is pushed, it sends a post request and two objects (a stream_id and an image) are sent to the view function. I can see from the debug page that the object contains both the stream_id and image in the POST and FILES objects respectively.

However, once the view function is hit, I try and initialize the form as follows:

```
uploadImageForm = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

And get validation errors thrown at me.

```
[28/May/2013 18:46:32] DEBUG [ct:194] uploadImage - method is post, errors:
<ul class="errorlist"><li>stream_id<ul class="errorlist">
<li>This field is required.</li></ul></li>
<li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
[28/May/2013 18:46:32] DEBUG [ct:195] cleaned data: {}
```

Any idea why?

My form:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    image.widget.attrs["onchange"]="this.form.submit();"
    stream_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    stream_id.widget.attrs["style"]="display:none;"

    def __init__(self,stream_id,*args,**kwrds):
        super(UploadImageForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwrds)
        self.fields['stream_id'].widget.attrs["value"]= stream_id
```

Model:

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    tracked_user = models.ForeignKey(TrackedUser)
    stream_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stream_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    end_time.null = True 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/")
    image.null = True 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Code in views.py:

```
def uploadImage(request):
    uploadImageForm = None
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        uploadImageForm = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        log.debug("uploadImage - method is post, errors: " +
            str(uploadImageForm.errors))
```

Interestingly enough, the bound form outputs as follows:

```
<p>
    <label for="id_image">Image:</label>
    <input id="id_image" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" type="file" />
</p>
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>This field is required.</li>
</ul>

<p>
    <label for="id_stream_id">Stream id:</label>
    <input id="id_stream_id" maxlength="100" name="stream_id"
        style="display:none;" type="text" value="&lt;QueryDict:
        {u&#39;stream_id&#39;:[u&#39;d21256f37601d2800b0b9604f0e94e1e&#39;],
        u&#39;csrfmiddlewaretoken&#39;:
        [u&#39;F0fmAD0VAj0RHrM0GGfnaSb6vTNgj9ZJ&#39;]}&gt;" />
</p>
```

Comment: Can you please post your model and form?

Comment: @Brandon Please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

All fields in a Django form are required by default, which is why you're getting errors on the Stream ID and other fields. Set `blank=True` on fields that you don't want to be required, or make optionally required by your form class:

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    tracked_user = models.ForeignKey(TrackedUser)
    stream_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    stream_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm not quite sure what you're doing with `ImageUploadForm`, but you're going to get initialization errors the way it's currently written. You aren't passing in the `stream_id` in your view either.

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    image.widget.attrs["onchange"]="this.form.submit();"
    stream_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    stream_id.widget.attrs["style"]="display:none;"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        stream_id = kwargs.pop('stream_id')
        super(UploadImageForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stream_id'].widget.attrs["value"]= stream_id
```

I'm thinking you meant to inherit from ModelForm...

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stream

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        stream_id = kwargs.pop('stream_id')

        super(UploadImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            # this is really bad practice. I would add this click handler
            # unobtrusively
            self.fields['image'].widget.attrs["onchange"] = "this.form.submit();"
            stream_id = self.fields['stream_id']

            # not sure what you're trying to accomplish here...
            self.fields['stream_id'].widget.attrs["style"] = "display:none;"

            stream_id.initial = stream_id
```